# Return a vector of objects of custom class from a getter: by const ref or by value

Tags: c++, oop, stdvector

I know this question has been asked for several times, however, I wasn't able to find a consensus on the recommended solution.
Suppose, I've a class which contains a vector of rel. large objects of a custom class, so the code looks like this:

```cpp
        class B
        {
        private:
            // 5 string data members
        public: 
            ...
        }

        class C
        {
        private:
            std::vector<B> vb;
    
        public:
            // option 1
            std::vector<B> get_vb() const { return vb; }
            // option2
            const std::vector<B> &get_vb() const { return vb; }
        }
```

My question is: considering performance, (N)RVO, dangling references implications and granting access to object internals, as Scott Meyers writes in his book,
is there a recommended way to return a vector of objects of custom class from a getter? If yes, then is it option 1 or 2? I use C++17.

I know that I can replace `std::vector<B>` with `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<B>> e.g.`, but it's not what I'm asking about.

Comment: My advice is to not return a vector at all. My advice is to not write a getter. By returning the member you turn the class into a plain dumb data storage which `std::vector<B>` already is. Rather than getters, write methods that allow callers to perform meaningful operations on the object. What is `C` actually?

Comment: As usual in C++, it depends. :-)  Is the vector long and B expensive to copy, perhaps returning a reference is the best choice. If, like Scott Meyers, you want to hide the fact that a vector is stored (or is it?!), returning by value might be better.

Comment: "Recommended" implies that the end results are equivalent. They're not. This is equivalent to asking "is it recommended way to go buy groceries, driving a car or taking a bus". It depends on your specific details. How far is the grocery store. Is there ample parking. Is there a bus that takes you there. Once you find the answers to these questions an intelligent decision becomes possible. Once you understand the differences between returning by value versus by reference, what each means, what it does, how it works, and what your program needs, an intelligent decision also becomes possible.

Comment: @Eljay you can't modify the `B`s through either, `vector` propagates `const`

Comment: class `C` is a collection so return iterators.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number
but what if I need to return the whole vector for example, to print all the strings of all the B objects inside an A object?

Comment: @quaz0 to do that you dont need to return the vector, it can be done with a `void C::print_all_As();`

Comment: In that case you might as well make the member public

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Ok I see your point now, thanks.

Comment: don't get me wrong, there is nothing wrong with plain dumb data storages. std containers grant you direct access to their elements, because thats what they are made for, but consider if it then really makes sense to make the member private (cf eg `std::vector::data()` which grants you direct access to the underlying array, thats not encapsulation, but a container that hides its elements from the user would be of little use)

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of other options you haven't explored.

- Expose a *view* of the `B`s, not specifically `std::vector<B>`

  `auto the_bs() const { return vb | std::ranges::views::all; }`
- Make `vb` public
- Expose iterators to `vb`

  `auto bs_begin() const { return vb.begin(); }`
  `auto bs_end() const { return vb.end(); }`

  Or just `begin`, `end` if `C` is meant to be a container of `B`s
- Don't expose the `B`s at all, have every operation on them as a member (or friend) of C

  `void print_all_bs() const;`

Different of these, and your getters, are appropriate choices in different situations. You need to think about what `C` is.

Comment: Ok, I see. Btw, C is not supposed to be just a collection of Bs, it's a standalone class with several other data members which I just--perhaps unwisely--dropped here. By using a vector I just want to show that that C may contain several B objects.